# How do I set a master password for macOS terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos

My friends like to troll me whenever I leave my computer open, they open all apps to make my computer crash, close my chrome tabs ecc. They know a little about tech so I don't want them to access my terminal and change anything. I would like to set a master password for my terminal, so that I every time I open it I have to insert the password. I would like the password to be different from the root password or my user's password.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This problem already has a well known and universally accepted solution and that is to simply lock your screen when not in use.

Comment: Your terminal is just a program on your computer. If they can't open that, they will just mess with something else. Jesse is right, the only *technical* way out is locking your screen. Everything else is a waste of time. The *right* way out here, personally, is having an honest talk with your friends about friendship, trust and boundaries.

Comment: I understand that it's too hard to pull the mouse to an active corner to manually lock the screen every time you leave. So maybe have a look at https://trendblog.net/lock-unlock-mac-bluetooth/ to auto-lock and auto-unlock your screen on walking away from your Mac/coming back, with your phone in your pocket.

Comment: If you really, really want to lock individual apps like the terminal, use https://apps.apple.com/us/app/applocker-password-lock-apps/id1132845904 But this is more a question for https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you guys. I found all of your answers very helpful, unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote you. @MarcusMüller I do the same to my friends, we are just messing around. @Philippos I think I didn't express myself clearly. I do not want to lock the app (even thought it is an absolutely acceptable solution to my problem) but I was wondering if there was a program that could set a master password for running a command as user. Just like when the command prompt asks for an admin password when typing `sudo` but for a set of commands (like rm).

Comment: @serax that does not exist, because "running a program" probably happens several times a second on your machine without you noticing